# message "Text is read-only" on multiple execution of un-changed buffer in python-mode

Tags: emacs, python-mode

I am setting up my emacs (24.3) with python-mode. I would like to be able to edit the python buffer and execute it in python shell with "C-c C-C". This mostly works. But I am getting "Text is read-only" error if I stay in python code buffer and execute the buffer again.

It doesn't matter if the buffer has been changed and saved or if it is the same un-changed buffer - repeated C-c C-c produces the error. The solution seems to be visiting python output buffer and coming back to python code buffer and then executing - this works. But this breaks my flow. Does anybody else have the same problem? is this some possible mis-configuration in my setup?

Regards, Roman

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question:  Is your working buffer somehow being set to `read-only`, and have you tried `(setq buffer-read-only nil)`?  Have you searched the source code of likely-suspect libraries for `buffer-read-only` to see what comes up?  Maybe it is something simple like focus is remaining in a buffer that is read-only and you want focus to be in a different buffer (e.g., your working buffer) -- in fact, that is probably the most likely scenario (i.e., focus is in a read-only buffer).

Comment: Can't reproduce with neither of both python-modes. Maybe give some details WRT to your setup.

Comment: I think I got it working now - my suspicion is that one of the packages I had was conflicting. I reinstalled the whole thing and python buffer evaluation is working as excepted now.

Comment: FWIW I've just experienced this issue, also on emacs 24.3.  For me I found killing the *Python* buffer and relaunching it implicitly with `C-c C-c` from the Python script I am trying to execute seems to fix the problem.

Comment: The advice from @BryceThomas fixed this issue for me.